# Aptana projects (web project versus php project and sql support)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aptana, aptana3

I am a beginner at using Aptana for web development (HTML,JavaScript,PHP,MySQL).

I would like to know, what is the difference between creating a PHP Project and
creating a Web Project?

Also, how do I enable MySQL (or in any case SQL) support in Aptana?
Do I need to install a plugin?

Thanks,

John Goche

Answer (score 4):

**Web Project** is `not specified to any language`. It may be in `HTML, CSS, JS, PHP, ASP, JSP` etc.

WHile, **PHP Project** is `specified to php only`. The way of highlighting the functions and indentation are according to php.

***You can say that PHP project is a PHP specific Web Project.***

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, PHP, ASP, or JSP may contend, but then HTML, CSS, and JS are used by all three. Is choosing one over the other about syntax highlighting the file properly then or what? I cannot find any reference to this issue in the Appcelerator Aptana/Titanium web development documentation. Thanks, John Goche

Answer (score 2):

As far as SQL support, this is what I did: Go to Help > Install new software. Add these repositories:

http://quantum.sourceforge.net/update-site

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/

Also, go here to get a MySQL JDBC driver:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html

Unpack it into the program folder somewhere (I don't know if it matters where).

Install gef, and then Quantum DB. Now, go to Window > Open Perspective > Other and choose Quantum DB. On the left-hand side you have a list of bookmarks. Add a bookmark, then click "Add driver" and then "Add External Jar". Browse to the Jar of your JDBC driver. Hit next.

Now you will see a pretty standard MySQL connection dialog with username, password, port, server and database name. Add a connection and you're good to go. You now have a visual MySQL editor inside Aptana.

Comment: Would I need the JDBC driver to just write a SQL script, not necessarily connecting to a Database?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you just want syntax highlighting? Because you could write an SQL script in any text editor.

Comment: Just looking for syntax highlighting and If I'm doing it correctly.